# Excel conditional ranking of user values between dates against all users in dates

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, ranking

I have trailing sales values relative to any given date for a particular salesperson on a sales event. I'm trying to rank a salesperson's sales level relative to all salespersons sales levels given the dates.

I'm having difficulty ranking duplicate rows.

Have tried sumproduct, countifs, rank.eq, with no luck.

Closest I can get is below with countifs:

```
=COUNTIFS(eventdate:eventdate,">"&eventdate1-1,eventdate:eventdate,"<="&eventdate,trailing:trailing,">="&trailing1)
-
COUNTIFS((eventdate:eventdate,">"&eventdate1-1,eventdate:eventdate,"<="&eventdate,userID:userID,"="&userID1)
```

Have also used SumProduct:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((T:T>(T27343-Settings!$B$6))*(T:T<=T27343)*(U:U>=U27343)))

psuedo:

SUMPRODUCT((DATE>DATE.MIN)*(DATE<=DATE.MAX)*(SALES>=this.SALES))
```

```
| UserID  |  Sales Date |Day's Trailing Sales| Rank|
|:--------|------------:|:------------------:|:---:|
| ab12    |     4/4/2019|                1050| 0
| ab12    |     4/4/2019|                1050| 0
| abc     |     4/4/2019|                1000| 2
| abc     |     4/4/2019|                1000| 2
| abc     |     4/4/2019|                1000| 2
| zxs     |     4/4/2019|                 850| 5
| zxs     |     4/4/2019|                 850| 5
| zxs     |     4/4/2019|                 850| 5
| zxs     |     4/4/2019|                 850| 5
| zxs     |     4/4/2019|                 850| 5
| ab12    |     4/3/2019|                 850|
| ab12    |     4/3/2019|                 850|
| zxs     |     4/3/2019|                 850|
```

I expect the rank to go 1, 2, 3 for each user for that date

Comment: Will the sales column always be sorted in descending order??

Comment: Good question. It will not. Dates are also not sorted

Comment: Does this mean they will be sorted by usedID? Can you sort by sales then date?

Comment: It would be sorted by the userID's sales value for that date. Each date will have a different sales amount per user.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the UserID is in column `A`, the date in column `B` and the day's sales in column `C`, Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A3<>A$2:A$15),--(B3=B$2:B$15),--(C3<C$2:C$15))+COUNTIFS(A$2:A3,A3,B$2:B3,B3)
```

Note: It also requires the data to be sorted by UserID